# Docker compose command no such file

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, containers

I've been attempting to containerize my php wev app (built on laravel) but I've run into a few issues

first I've found that the container exits after executing a command so I moved the building script to a different container (migrations and composer install)

I made a script called init.sh that contains the build instructions but whenever I run them from the `command` in `docker-compose.yml` I get no such file or directory.

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM nimmis/apache-php7


COPY apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN service apache2 restart
```

this is my docker-compose.ym

```
version: "3"

volumes:
    db-data:
        external: false

services:
    db:
        image: mysql/mysql-server
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql-server

    migrations:
        build: .
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html/books
        depends_on:
            - app
        command: 
            # - /var/www/html/books/artisan migrate 
            # - chmod 777 /var/www/html/init.sh
            - /var/www/html/books/init.sh
            # - /var/www/html/init.sh
        environment:
            - ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true

    app:
        build: .
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html/books
        ports: 
            - "8081:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            - ALLOW_OVERRIDE=true
```

the commented parts a different attempts to run the script correctly.

I'm trying to run it on windows 10 using docker toolbox

What am I doing wrong? and is this the correct approach?

Comment: Which one is it saying no such file for?

Comment: What's in the Dockerfile? Whats init.sh?

Comment: I've updated my question ... @JayBlanchard the migrations one says no such file what it attempts to run command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what was wrong ... it was a permissions issue.

when I set the permissions to be executable it worked fine ...

so now all I had to do was adjust my dockerfile to be

```
FROM nimmis/apache-php7

COPY . /var/www/html/books

COPY start.sh /

RUN chmod +x /start.sh

COPY apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

The RUN directive will execute something in the container when the container is building, not when the container is executing.

To that end, your Dockerfile should look something more like this:

```
FROM nimmis/apache-php7


COPY apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/path/to/init.sh"]
CMD ["apache2", "-DFOREGROUND", "-k", "start"]
```

The Entrypoint directive will run right before the CMD directive, irrespective if you pass a command into the container at boot.

So, you'll want to make init.sh execute the command the container passes to it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# init.sh

# todo: whatever init.sh does...

# Execute the CMD passed to the container:
exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
  volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html/books
```

use

```
 volumes:
            - folder_containg_sh:/var/www/html/books  #relative path to script
```

in docker-compose file

Comment: You can't reference a file as a volume

Comment: but folder containing files can be attached, Ok i used file in answer i will update

Comment: Yes of course; if it's a folder then you're all set :-) You just can't reference a file directly as that would not mount appropriately. Cheers!

Comment: the `.` refers to the project directory which contains the `.sh` file ... so it should be working but it's not... any idea?

Comment: not sure its skiping because of lots of files and folders, try makeing seperat folder and give that path in volume section. Why cant you add the file while building docker image any strong reason?

Comment: executing the file by using CMD ... will exit the container after the command is done .. I might try to COPY the file and execute it